# How to 3d scan images in blender

Tags: 3d-view, photorealism

I want to know how can real world objects can be 3d scanned in blender so that we can use it in blender. Please tell all steps of doing that and also the time required in doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to do it all in Blender.

You'll have to use a 3D scan tool (there are some for your smartphone like Scann3D, 3D Creator, Scandy Pro).

Then you'll export your mesh in a format that Blender understands, like OBJ and import it in Blender (File->Import).

Comment: Which is the best tool for pc

Comment: You may have to try a couple of them :)